# what is max number computer in lan?

Tags: networking, window

I want know the number max PC, I can set up same LAN with Window7. Thanks How many PC's can theoretically be setup on a Windows 7 Lan, assuming you had an infinite number of switches and cables. I think the answer is 100. But I'm not sure - it might be unlimited. Can any networking experts tell me?

Comment: "Enough". And a good bit more than 100. There is some *theoretical* upper-bound .. depends on logical *and* physical LAN makeup though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk365/technologies_tech_note09186a0080093f33.shtml

more people than you will ever get to know^^

with the subnetmask windows set per default(255.255.255.0) for LANS 255-2=253 Hosts. But you can change that if needed

Comment: I think your math is not correct: it should be 256 - 2 = 254
Two reserved addresses are 255.255.255.0 and 255.255.255.255